# Multiple Maps updating a log file synchronisation issue

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am a updating a file which is on HDFS.

How could I ensure that the changes done by all the maps are there on file i.e if the write actions on the file were synchronized?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Hadoop - The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021773.do)

> **Multiple writers, arbitrary file modifications**
>   Files in HDFS may be written to by a single writer. Writes are always made at the
>   end of the file. There is no support for multiple writers or for modifications at
>   arbitrary offsets in the file. (These might be supported in the future, but they are
>   likely to be relatively inefficient.)

It's practically not possible for an application level synchronization because of the nature of Hadoop (multiple nodes/mappers/reducers etc).

The [MapR distribution of Apache Hadoop](http://www.mapr.com/Download-document/9-NFS-Technical-Brief) supports random reads and writes with support for multiple readers and writers simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

HDFS files are not mutable. So you can only append to them. 
The issue of concurrent append is covered here : [Is it possible to append to HDFS file from multiple clients in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389594/is-it-possible-to-append-to-hdfs-file-from-multiple-clients-in-parallel) 
In a nutshell - you should not. 
I would also point out that it is not in "mr spirit". If you want to collect some data from a mappers and aggregate it together - it is exactly role of the reducer.