# Merging multiple LZO compressed files on HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, compression, hdfs

Let's say I have this structure on HDFS:

```
/dir1
    /dir2
        /Name1_2015/
            file1.lzo
            file2.lzo
            file3.lzo
        /Name2_2015
            file1.lzo
            file2.lzo

    Name1_2015.lzo
```

I would like to merge each file of each directory in 'dir2' and append the result to the file in /dir1/DirName.lzo

For example, for /dir1/dir2/Name1_2015, I want to merge file1.lzo, file2.lzo, file3.lzo and append it to /dir1/Name1_2015.lzo

Each files are LZO compressed.

How can I do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care much about parallelism here's a bash one-liner:

```
for d in `hdfs dfs -ls /dir2 | grep -oP '(?<=/)[^/]+$'` ; do hdfs dfs -cat /dir2/$d/*.lzo | lzop -d | lzop  | hdfs dfs -put - /dir1/$d.lzo ; done
```

You can extract all files in parallel using map-reduce. But how do you create one archive from multiple files in parallel? As far as I know, it is not possible to write to a single HDFS file from multiple processes concurrently. So as it's not possible we come up with a single node solution anyway.

Comment: With this script data are pulled to a local node then pushed to HDFS, right ? Is there a way to avoid retrieving all data to a single node, merging then pushing the merged file ?

Comment: Even if I want to append is it not possible ? As it's LZO compressed I have to decompress main file append to it then re-compress it. I can't append directly LZO because of headers, right ?

Comment: I was wrong about append, we can't append concurrently too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389594/is-it-possible-to-append-to-hdfs-file-from-multiple-clients-in-parallel
HDFS design implies that there is only one writer per file.

Comment: Even If I use FileUtil.copyMerge to merge 2 non compressed files, it will pull all the data to a single node before merging ?

Comment: Yes, it will be done in jvm memory, check out source code
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with Hive, as follows:

1. Rename the subdirectories to name=1_2015 and name=2_2015
2. CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE sending_table
   (
   all_content string
   )
   PARTITIONED BY (name string) 
   LOCATION "/dir1/dir2"
   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY {a column delimiter that you know doesn't show up in any of the lines}
3. Make a second table that looks like the first, named "receiving", but with no partitions, and in a different directory.
4. Run this:

   SET mapreduce.job.reduces=1 # this guarantees it'll make one file
   SET mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec=com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec
   SET hive.exec.compress.output=true
   SET mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress=true

   insert into table receiving 
   select all_content from sending_table

Answer (score 1):

You can try to archive all the individual LZO files into HAR (Hadoop Archive). I think its overhead to merge all the files into single LZO.

Comment: I know its overhead to merge all files but i really need à single merged file to process it later